# Blur Behind Div CSS

Tags: html, css, blur

I am working on a website, and I need to blue the background behind a div, and I am unable to find a way to do it using CSS.

I found an article that showed how to do it, but I was unable to accurately replicate it.

Here is the article: https://jordanhollinger.com/2014/01/29/css-gaussian-blur-behind-a-translucent-box/

Here is my page: http://biolinks.redxte.ch/blur

If anyone can let me know what I'm doing wrong that would be great, thanks.

Comment: hello, me again. i was just perusing my past fiddles and I found this https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/81v5ge58/  It's a blur-background-but-not-text on hover thing. Take a look at it, You might spot something that might help

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
```

It will blur area behind the element.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=backdrop-filter
Only Edge & Safri support this filter

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=backdrop-filter Now also supported by chrome and android.

Comment: is this ok now? still not supported by firefox which is a shame

Comment: According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/css-backdrop-filter) , `backdrop-filter` will be added in the upcoming stable version of Firefox (103), set to be released in 07/2022.

Comment: Weird bug. With backdrop-filter it goes over sticky elements when scrolling. (MS Edge:Chromium)

Comment: Works fine with Firefox too, nowadays :)

Answer (score 2):

You were so close!

Remove `position: relative` on `.name-container` and add it to `.head`

**Update**:

Remove `.name-bg`, (use `display: none` if neccessary), and change `.name` z-index to 1 or greater. Then add this code.

```
.name:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-position: center -373px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  filter: blur(10px);
  border-radius: 8px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.head, .name:after {
  background-size: 1500px auto; /* Really, this */
  background-position: center; /* and this is the only code .head needs  */
  background: url('http://il9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/3403961/thumb/1.jpg');
}
```

**Note**: As the site used, you have to set an absolute `background-size` unfortunately. Also, as `@media` code gets used, you gotta tinker with the code a little.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That works, but not quite for what I need it to do. That makes the entire background blurred, and not just the part behind the `.name` div.

Comment: @RedXTech I have tested it on your site and got it working. Were you able to?

Answer (score 0):

add the blur filter to the `#pp` css (the img id used within your .name class) and remove it from the name-bg (which is affecting the whole background). That should work better for you. 10px might be a bit much. I previewed it (see image)

Hope this helps

[image: Gabe Dunn 10 px blur]

EDIT:

After a closer look at your code (and seeing your comment, which clarified the question), you already have margin set to 0 auto around the name container, and the `name-bg class` is already being sized by this (it is being altered by the addition of the top/right/bottom/left coordinates) I adjusted the top/right/left/bottom to 2 or -2 (see fiddle), which decreased the size of the background div. I also changed the positioning to `relative`, so that when resized, that it will still come up in the middle.

https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/rhav95o1/ :fiddle

I think this is closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: in the first image posted i'd forgotten to turn off the webkit blur.. actually looks okay

Comment: That's neat, but what I need is the background picture to be blurred behind the .name div, and nowhere else :/

Comment: Thanks for all the effort, but I'm not really seeing a blur on that fiddle.

Comment: @RedXTech well increase the blur or the blur area then..  here to assist, not tot do the work for you

Comment: Still nothing for some reason.

Comment: Accept is for when it works, up votes acknowledge people's time and effort

Comment: Cool.  FYI, I upvoted your question. Thanks for the vote. I hope it helped you come closer to a solution at least..

Answer (score 0):

Yet another implementation. Note that the downside is that you have to duplicate the text in order to get the same height in both places (can probably do this with JS, or something, to be little cleaner)

html:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>Blurred box</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, omnis quam. Eos distinctio amet nisi ex ipsam ab, accusamus quod, natus nulla modi obcaecati labore nostrum cupiditate laboriosam. Doloremque, omnis!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inner with-text">
    <h1>Blurred box</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, omnis quam. Eos distinctio amet nisi ex ipsam ab, accusamus quod, natus nulla modi obcaecati labore nostrum cupiditate laboriosam. Doloremque, omnis!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

scss:

```
@import "compass/css3";

$normal-img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/San_Stefano_Grand_Plaza%2C_Alexandria%2C_Egypt.jpg";

.outer{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image:url($normal-img);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.inner {
  background-image:url($normal-img);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  @include background-size(cover);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  filter:blur(6px);
  width:500px;
  left:-webkit-calc( 50% - 250px );
  top:20%;
  position:absolute;
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
  color: transparent;
  &.with-text {
    color: white;
    opacity: .5;
    filter: none;
    background: grey;
  }
}
```

pen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BxgyNR?